# Formal words for "can"

Tags: word-choice, formal-language

> Using a sample page of a website and having access to the properties of each element, the user **can** generate a wrapper for similar pages.

What are formal words for "can", for example "is able"?!

I think in this sentence, the first parts *enables the user* (or makes it possible for the user) to do something.

Comment: Yes, but what bothers you with "can"?

Comment: @Stephie  I added my comment to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have *two* issues here.

1. Grammar structure.

   If you look at the original sentence you will notice that the subject is *the user* and the first part describes *by what means* the user does something:

   > Using a sample page of a website and having access to the properties of each element**,** [the user] [can] [generate a wrapper for similar pages.]

   The same is true for *is able*:

   > Using a sample page of a website and having access to the properties of each element**,** [the user] [is able to] [generate a wrapper for similar pages.]

   Once you change to *enable*, the whole first part becomes the subject, the comma is lost and the user is the object of the sentence (hint: the structure is always subject-verb-object, SVO)

   > [Using a sample page of a website and having access to the properties of each element] [enables] [the user] [to generate a wrapper for similar pages.]
2. Style.

   Whether *can* or *is able* is the better choice is
   a) a question of personal style and
   b) context.

   In my experience the "more complicated" or "formal" word *can* be better, but *is not always neccesarily so*. In this case, my *gut feeling* (I'm neither a linguist nor a native speaker) would be that *can*  focuses on the fact of what the user does, *enable* points out the possibility to do something he previously couldn't. English is a language that (compared to other languages I know) gives less precedence<sup>1</sup> to "specialized" words than others, so frankly, if *can* fits, I'd use it. Overuse of "formal words" can appear forced and even unnatural, but that is probably something for another SE site.

---

<sup>1</sup> See? I'm falling into the "big words trap" myself..

Comment: I got you that you mean in opposite with some other languages, English doesn't try to be very formal but smooth and moderate.

Comment: @Ahmad, yes. English is often quite matter-of-fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "can" or "be able to" in formal English. However, according to The Free Dictionary and the OP's indication, "be able to" is more formal than "can".